# Astrology Charts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, graphics

Is anyone here using `LaTeX` to typeset astrology charts?  Would I use `pgf/tikz` an appropriate tool to use for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [marvosym](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/marvosym/marvodoc.pdf) font package. It has some astrology symbols in it. I am not sure though if it is adequate for what you are looking. However, with a special font it will be much easier than pgf/TikZ.

Comment: I already have starfont installed. I was looking for something to draw the chart wheel.

Comment: @Larry I am afraid then you will have to use TikZ perhaps with a font combination `astro` is another font you can use in conjuction with TikZ.

Comment: @Yiannis: I'm already looking at the documentation for TikZ. I'm a programmer by trade, so it's not really that onerous. I'll be writing a program using the Swiss Ephemeris to generate the LaTeX input.

Comment: @Larry That is great once you finish it will be a nice example to show here.

Comment: @Yiannis: I've installed TikZ on both my laptop and desktop machines. I'll post an answer after working through the tutorials and trying a few things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just finished a sample chart in the Vedic/Traditional style with boxy houses. Should I post the LaTeX code in an answer?

Comment: @Larry you do that, this way anyone with a similar problem can follow it up.

Answer (score 5):

Matthew Skala has a few resources on this topic:

- http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/astrology/astro-latex.php
- http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/entry/107

Here is an example chart from the manual:
[image]

Comment: The links to actual packages on the page are dead.

Comment: Sorry, I've added a link to his new blog where the links should work.

Comment: That looks really nice. I'm planning to learn TikZ anyway, as I'm going to need to tweak the layout a little.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with for a Traditional/Vedic style chart. It could probably use some improvement, but I'm still learning TikZ, so I'd appreciate helpful edits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usepackage{starfont}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3in,-3in) -- (-3in,3in);
  \draw (-3in,-3in) -- (3in,-3in);
  \draw (3in,-3in) -- (3in,3in);
  \draw (-3in,3in) -- (3in,3in);
  \draw (-3in,-1.5in) -- (3in,-1.5in);
  \draw (-3in,1.5in) -- (3in,1.5in);
  \draw (-1.5in,-3in) -- (-1.5in,3in);
  \draw (1.5in,-3in) -- (1.5in,3in);
  \draw (0in,1.5in) -- (0in,3in);
  \draw (0in,-1.5in) -- (0in,-3in);
  \draw (-3in,0in) -- (-1.5in,0in);
  \draw (1.5in,0in) -- (3in,0in);
  \node [text width=2.75in] at (0in,0in) {
      \begin{center}
       Larry Coleman \\
       November 12, 1967 
       7:20 AM EST \\
       Belleville, MI 83:29W 42:12N \\
       Natal Chart
       \end{center}
  };
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (-3in,0in) {
    I. Scorpio. \\
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Mercury & 1:45 \\
    Ascendant & 18:29 \\
    Sun & 19:26 \\ 
    Neptune & 23:55 
    \end{tabular}
  };
  \node [below right] at (-3in,-1.5in) {II. Sagittarius.};
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (-1.5in,-1.5in) {
    III. Capricorn. \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      Mars & 15:14
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (0in,-1.5in) {
    IV. Aquarius.};
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (1.5in,-1.5in) {
    V. Pisces. \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      \Chiron & 25:16 \Retrograde \\ 
      \Moon & 28:40
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (1.5in,0in) {
    VI. Aries. \\
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Saturn & 6:17 \Retrograde \\
      North Node & 26:37 \Retrograde
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \node [below right] at (1.5in,1.5in) {VII. Taurus.};
  \node [below right] at (1.5in,3in) {VIII. Gemini.};
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (0in,3in) {
    IX. Cancer. \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      Fortune & 9:15 
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \node [below right] at (-1.5in,3in) {X. Leo};
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (-3in,3in) {
    XI. Virgo. \  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Midheaven & 0:23 \\
    Jupiter & 3:25 \\
    Pluto & 22:21 \\
    Uranus & 27:58
    \end{tabular}
  }; 
  \node [below right,text width=1in] at (-3in,1.5in) {
    XII. Libra. \\
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      Venus & 2:53
      \end{tabular}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post the solution. One possibility is to automate the calculations, i.e., one could do `\dateofbirth{}` and get a chart! Is there a link as to how one works all these out?

Comment: @Yiannis: I copied and pasted the planet's positions from the output of another program. I'm working on a program using the Swiss Ephemeris that will output something similar to what I've posted. I'll let you know.